# Why does Combustion Man keep blowing himself up?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

According to the Avatar Wikia, [Combustion Man was unable to control his power early on and accidentally blew up his arm and leg](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Combustion_Man).

In Avatar: The Last Air Bender, two times he is seen using his power after clearly suffering a head blow and being disoriented:

1. The first time is when Toph protects herself from Combustion Man's attack and a pebble "coincidentally" hits his third eye. He becomes disoriented and tries to use his power but it backfires on him and and he hurts himself even more. (Why didn't he just run after them...)
2. After Sokka hits him in the head with his boomerang, he is heavily disoriented and tries to his power, killing himself in the process.

Why does he keep blowing himself up? Also, how did he survive so long? He's an assassin so clearly he would have had to fight others a lot and I'm sure at some point he would have been hit in his third eye and then the person would have been able to kill Combustion Man while he's disoriented.

Comment: I believe you are referring to Sparky-Sparky-Boom-Man?

Comment: Same reason drunk people do self-destructive things.  When your thinking is impaired you don't always act rationally.

Answer (score 5):

To preface this, through his interactions with Zuko, It seems that Combustion man has a lot of pride related to his work, given that he refuses to call off a mission, despite his employer (Zuko) calling off the attack. I think this interaction serves as the primary example of his moral code/compass. With that in mind, lets explore some potential answers to your question:

1. Combustion man is willing to fight through the pain and complete his task no matter the opposition. This could be pride of professionalism, it's really up for you to observe/decide. As this is likely the answer to your question, please keep in mind that he was also fighting children. You could imagine that a professional hit-man would refuse to be bested by a few 12/13 year-olds.
2. Reactionary combat. Through disorientation and combat instincts, Combustion man's critical thinking skills are severely impaired, resulting in the aforementioned results of his attacks.